# About mongodb index

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-indexes

i have one question about mongodb index. 
Suppose we have two models:

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :user_id
  field :borrower_id

  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :books
end
```

## Question

If i wonner find some books:

```
current_user.books.roder_by(:created_at.desc)
```

which index should i create for Book

```
index({user_id: 1, created_at: -1})
```

or

```
index({user_id: 1})
index({created_at: -1)
```

and why?

Comment: The compound index since MongoDB cannot use index intersectionijng for sort and find, separately as such the latter two indexes would be sup-optimal to answer the query. Of course index intersecioning would be sub-optimal anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the compound index due to a number of limitations within MongoDBs (new) index intersectioning which means that two indexes cannot be used separately for find and sort of a query: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort as such in this case two separate indexes are not optimal for answering your query, only one index will be used, most likel it will be a in-memory sort limited to 32MB of RAM.

It is also good to note that ndex intersectioning is a last resort at all times. You should only do it if you cannot performantly create a compound index to cover the query since intersectioning is very expensive to begin with.